# How do you add constraints to a label in a UICollectionView header?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a label that I cant add constraints to because it is in a Collection Reusable View, which doesn't have a `viewDidLoad` method. Is it possible to constrain the header so it is always 15 px from the left?

I tried adding constraints normally, but again, the Reusable View doesnt have a view for some reason. The other solutions I looked at all use a view of sorts.

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        headerTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        headerTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        headerTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        headerTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        headerTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        headerTitle.frame = bounds
    }
```

This code throws the error `Cannot find 'view' in scope` which im assuming is a Reusable View thing rather than a non existent view. Here is the rest of my code:

```
class HeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let identifier = "homeheader"
    
    private let headerTitle = UILabel()
    private let newDataSet = UIButton()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        
        headerTitle.text = "AppTitle"
        headerTitle.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32.0, weight: .bold)
        headerTitle.textAlignment = .left
        headerTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        
        addSubview(headerTitle)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        headerTitle.frame = bounds //<-- want to replace this line with the constraints
    }
}
```

I'm hoping the solution works with buttons too. This is my desired output:
[desired output from constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAjRe.png)

Comment: Did you try `CGRect`? Just do headerTitle.frame = `CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: 50)`. Code not tested though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to put constraints on a label but you don't have a parent view of that label. Constraints need some view to hold onto in order to be functional.

Comment: How can I add a view? Does it need to passed in or can I create it here?